# Need Email Client ASAP Please

Tags: email, web-browser, email-client, imap, pop3

I would like a email client that lets me add about 10-15 different emails and manage them. I want it to be online. I have searched for hours to find one but cant. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean with "*I want it to be online.*", but if you want a web-application/-interface i can recommend [RainLoop](https://www.rainloop.net/); but to be clear: it is just a IMAP-interface (with CardDAV- & .vcf-/.csv-support for contact information and other nice features like OpenPGP). -- there is also a [demo online](https://mail.rainloop.net/).

Comment: We don't know any software for ASAP, nor do we know any client by that name (the only software going by that name I know of is [Asap](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Asap), and that's no mail client). Maybe you can [edit] your post and name a different target? For example, it could be a web application you host yourself (then please specify if it can run on the same machine the mail server runs on).

Answer (score -1):

[Thunderbirds](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) a go.
Wouldn't Mozilla's mail client be enough?

Comment: He said **I want it to be online**, which Thunderbird obviously isn't.